# Is it possible to write complex functional tests for Android?

Tags: android, junit, functional-testing, android-testing

Is it possible to have something like this? Either with Android/Robotium test frameworks or any other solutions

```
public void testAll() throws Exception {
    test_001_LoginActivity();
    test_002_MainActivity();
}

public void test_001_LoginActivity() throws Exception {
    startActivity();
    test_001_LoginActivity_001_emptyUsername();
    test_001_LoginActivity_002_emptyPassword();
    test_001_LoginActivity_003_incorrectValues();
    test_001_LoginActivity_004_correctValues(); // MainActivity is opened on success
}

public void test_002_MainActivity() throws Exception {
    test_002_MainActivity_001_profile();
    test_002_MainActivity_002_list();
    test_002_MainActivity_003_logout();
}
```

The idea is to have `test_001_LoginActivity()` and `test_002_MainActivity()`contain all the corresponding activity test without recreation of the activities. And to have a result displayed like that:

```
test_001_LoginActivity() - OK
--->test_001_LoginActivity_001_emptyUsername() - OK
--->test_001_LoginActivity_002_emptyPassword() - OK
--->test_001_LoginActivity_003_incorrectValues() - OK
--->test_001_LoginActivity_004_correctValues() - OK

test_002_MainActivity() - NOK
--->test_002_MainActivity_001_profile() - OK
--->test_002_MainActivity_002_list() - NOK
--->test_002_MainActivity_003_logout() - OK
```

Which means that all tests for `LoginActivity` are passed successfully; `test_002_MainActivity_002_list()` test failed for `MainActivity`, but `test_002_MainActivity_003_logout()` test was passed(since activity was not recreated)

I'm new to testing, so maybe I'm getting it wrong and tests are intended to be executed for a brand new activity instance always?

Answer (score 0):

What your are trying to do might be possible if you rename all test_00X_METHOD methods becuase currently it will go to total mess because "test" prefix before a methods has a special meaning for jUnit Framework - beside all will be executed by you from testAll() also all methods will be executed latere seperately as jUnit run all methods with "test" prefix as seperate test case and application is even restarted between those methods. So it should works fine if you throw away all "test" prefixes but keep it for testAll(). And you needn't "startActivity()" method at the begining of test_001_LoginActivity() because Activity is automaticaly started - which activity? Activity you passed as type parameter to this class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html.

I hope this answer is useful for you.

Krzysiek,
Bitbar Software Engineer

Comment: For the solution, you've suggested, I get only one pass mark in the log - for the `testAll` method. And I want to have all the tests appear as separate marks

Comment: hmmm so what you try to do doesn't fit to jUnit architecture as it run all 'test...' method seperatly and shows results from it. Of course, your 'test..' methods inside testAll will be run too but manually by you and they result will be common with testAll and then those methods from inside testAll will be run seperatly as well. So maybe use asserts instead "test..." prefix? Result will be one for testAll but if sth will fail you will know what exactly and where...or maybe there is solution for it but I don't know it...